# VB.NET stopping strings being automatically split by spaces

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, space

I am building a program in VB that populates a listbox with all the songs in a chosen folder and opens them with media player when you click on them in the list. All of that works but my problem is that pretty much no matter what I do (I've tested this with WMP, VLC, and Winamp) it splits up the argument string by spaces, for example if the file path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Test song.mp3`, it will try to open in sequence: `C:\Program`, then `Files`, then `(x86)\Test`, then `song.mp3`. It works on file paths containing no spaces, but else it always fails.

```
    Private Sub SongListBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SongListBox.Click
    Dim song As String = SongListBox.SelectedIndex
    If SongListBox.SelectedIndex = "-1" Then

    Else
        Dim SongPath As String = Pathlist.Items.Item(song)
        Dim SongProcess As New ProcessStartInfo
        SongProcess.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Winamp\winamp.exe"
        SongProcess.Arguments = SongPath
        SongProcess.UseShellExecute = True
        SongProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        MsgBox(Pathlist.Items.Item(song), MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Song")
        Dim SongStart As Process = Process.Start(SongProcess)
        SongListBox.Select()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the FileName with escaped quotes? `SongProcess.FileName = """C:\Program Files\Winamp\winamp.exe"""` - and, yes, that is how VB.NET escapes quotes.

Comment: It is not clear `C:\Program, then Files, then (x86)\Test, then song.mp3` , how it actually looks like? is `,` is present or not?

Comment: Cheers, Phil. Worked like a charm.